# Prove the existence of $f$ and why the function $f_n$ is constructed

Tags: functions, induction, recursion, natural-numbers, constructive-mathematics

I'm not an experienced person in proof.

This is a proposition in Amann/Escher's ***Analysis***.

Let $X$ be a nonempty set and $\mathcal{a}\in X$. For each $n \in\mathbb{N}^{\times}$, let $V_{n}:X^{n} \to X$ be a function. Then there is a unique function $f:\mathbb{N} \to X$ with the following properties:

(i) $f(0)=a$

(ii) $f(n+1)=V_{n+1}(f(0),f(1),...,f(n))$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$

The proof of uniqueness is trivial. My question is about the existence.

In Amann's book, he first claims that, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a function $f_{n}:\{0,1,...,n\}\to X$ such that

$(0\le k<n)$

$f_{n}(0)=a$

$f_{n}(k)=f_{k}(k)$

$f_{n}(k+1)=V_{k+1}(f_{n}(0),\dots,f_{n}(k))$

and then he uses induction to prove that $f_{n}$ exists. $\textbf{But why construct this function?}$

I try to find the answer in requirements for function $f$.

In my opinion, in order to prove the function $f$ with (i),(ii) is existence. It is necessary to connect $f$ and $V_{n+1}$. So I guess the role of $f_{n}$ as a bridge. But I have no idea how to make this work.

And in my knowledge stoage, to prove a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$ is existence. It is equal to prove $\forall n\in \mathbb N$, specifies exactly one element of $X$ or use the relation language. $\textbf{Is there something I'm missing here?}$

From $f(0)=a,f(n+1)=V_{n+1}(f(0),f(1),...,f(n))$,$n\in \mathbb{N}$

I  find that $f(1)=V_{1}(f(0))=V_{1}(a),f(2)=V_{2}(f(0),f(1))=V_{2}(a,V_{1}(a))...$

But I don't know if this works for my question.

I also notice that in next part, $f$ was defined:
$f:\mathbb{N}\to X, f(n):=\begin{cases}a,n=0
 \\
\\f_{n}(n),n\in \mathbb{N}^{\times } 
\end{cases} $

But I still can't figure out what works.

What should I do now? I can not find a road to finish the proposition. My wording may be incorrect as well.

Comment: Since you are not bothered about uniqueness, Can u fix the question, from the looks of it, what if we define the function $f$ based on the properties ie.,, $f(n+1)$ by definition is equal to $V_{n+1}(f(0),f(1),...,f(n))$ ?

Comment: "Your" definition is too informal: it ends up with a "$\dots$" which won't do. The book's careful treatment is intended to avoid these "and so on" fudges.

Comment: @Balajisb same comment as ancient mathematician. Cycle motor: this is the whole point and might be considered as an answer to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting observation and the authors write nothing to explain what is happening (imho a little remark would be fine).
Why defining the $\{f_n\}$? Because you get a sort of procedure just using $f$ and $V$ but you will not prove the *existence* of such $f$.
This has got to do with the set theoretic *definition* of function.

Roughly, a function $f\colon X \to Y$ is defined once you 1) write down all the pairs $(x, f(x))$ as in the finite case or 2) have a set theoretic property $\mathbf{P}(x,y)$ and

$$
f = \{(x,y) \in X \times Y \mid \mathbf{P}(x,y)\}\,.
$$

I'll try to be clearer by showing an example. Consider the sequence $s \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by

$$
\begin{align}
s_0 &= 1; \\
s_{n+1} &= n^2 \quad \text{for all}\; n \in \mathbb{N}. 
\end{align}
$$

The definition of $s$ gives **explicit** instructions how to compute $s_x$ for any $x \in \mathbb{N}$. More precisely, there is a property $\mathbf{P}$ such that

$$
s_x = y \quad \text{iff} \quad \mathbf{P}(x,y)\,;
$$

namely, let $\mathbf{P}(x,y)$ be "either $x=0$ and $y=1$ or, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x=n+1$ and $y = n^2$". Now, cosider the following. The sequence $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is defined by

$$
\begin{align}
f_0 &= 1; \\
f_{n+1} &= f_n \cdot (n+1) \quad \text{for all}\; n \in \mathbb{N}. 
\end{align}
$$

This sequence, despite its apparent resemblance to the precedent, is deeply different in that there is **no obvious way** to formulate a property $\mathbf{P}$ defining $f$ without using the same $f$ to be defined. The instructions for computing $f$ only tell us how to compute $f_x$ *provided* that the value of $f$, for some smaller number, was already computed.

Going back to your question, if you want to prove the existence of $f$, you need to join an infinity of its *approximations* $f_n$ (note that each $f_n$ is defined on $\{0,\dots,n\}$ and not on the whole naturals). Each $f_n$ is well defined and represents a finite $n$-step computation.

---

You can find more about this topic reading the following:
Hrbaceck, Jech - *Introduction to Set Theory* (3rd ed. 1999) - page 47;
Halmos - *Naive Set Theory* (1960) - Sec. 12 page 38;
Enderton - *Elements of Set Theory* (1977) - page 73.